# Using variables in JMeter to generate incremental load

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, stress-testing

I need to perform an incremental load test using Jmeter.
Expected behaviour will look like this:
1st iteration - 10 threads
2nd iteration - 20 threads
3rd iteration - 30 threads
etc

I tried use variables in Counter: set Exported Variable Name as "currentThreads", and Counter was placed in the same ThreadsGroup.
So value of "Number of Threads" in Thread Properties looks like ${__P(currentThreads)}.
But whole load came in loop and constantly repeated 1 thread at a time.

Is there any proper way to do that?

[Thread Group Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSGgr.png)
[Counter Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQSrN.png)

Answer (score 0):

The number of threads in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) is fixed and being evaluated/applied when the test starts.

As of [JMeter 5.6.2](https://lists.apache.org/thread/49dnwvyozy535ogwqvdvbkwkgk0xkrrl) your requirement cannot be implemented, if you know how long does "iteration" take you can consider playing with [ramp-up period](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period) and/or [pacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345023/how-to-implement-pacing-in-jmeter)